# beautifulsoup It does not extract the text. The text I want to extract is this (is A Valid Tron Address)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

beautifulsoup It does not extract the text. The text I want to extract is this (is A Valid Tron Address)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.walletvalidator.com/tron-wallet-validator/#TWWesZx6P88Ru6v7zRZwYWjy7wr3rnYoYi"

html = requests.get(url)

htmlParse = BeautifulSoup(html.content, 'html.parser')

result = htmlParse.find("div", id="status")
print(result)
```

Comment: The API doesn't take arguments in the URL (fragment doesn't get sent to the server anyway), needs a POST request and returns JSON not HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The status is obtained from another request. If the request is unsuccessful, the status will be False. The validity status is not initially present on the page and cannot be retrieved as it is dynamic.

```
import requests


def validate_tron_address(address):
    validate_url = "https://www.walletvalidator.com/tron-wallet-validator/"
    payload = f"validate={address}"
    headers = {
      'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
    }
    status = requests.request("POST", validate_url, headers=headers, data=payload).json()['ok']
    if status:
        return 'is A Valid Tron Address'
    else:
        return 'is Not A Valid Tron Address'


url = "https://www.walletvalidator.com/tron-wallet-validator/#TWWesZx6P88Ru6v7zRZwYWjy7wr3rnYoYi"
print(validate_tron_address(url.split('#')[-1]))
```

OUTPUT:

```
is A Valid Tron Address
```

Comment: I want to give this output: (is A Valid Tron Address)

Comment: no problem, iam update my post

Comment: Thank you for your answer
Can you please tell me the bitcoin validation code for this site
I want it to tell me if the bitcoin address is correct or not
https://www.blockonomics.co/#/search?q=bc1qtm67e9tljrgdrqz7q85kn28ef898xeag0mhss9

Comment: If the answer helped you, mark it as Accepted. Regarding the second site, in order to get validation, you need to register on the site. Payload required `client_challenge` to get validation

Comment: Well, you give me a code so that I can validate the bitcoin address
It doesn't matter what site it is from